# How can I make the eye blinking in randomly durations?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside the Scale method I'm checking if it's in random duration mode:

```
if (randomDuration)
                {
                    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(eyesparts[i], maxSize, Random.Range(0.1f, 1)));
                }
                else
                {
                    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(eyesparts[i], maxSize, duration));
                }
```

The problem is that it's not completing the blinking before picking up a new random duration that cause the eye to blink too fast or sometimes the minSize not finish before the maxSize since the eye is built from two parts the random duration making the parts not close/open equal.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EyeBlinking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject eyePrefab;
    [Range(0.1f, 50f)]
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool oppositeDirection = false;
    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool randomDuration = false;
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfEyes = 1;

    private List<GameObject> eyesparts = new List<GameObject>();
    private bool coroutineIsRunning = false;
    private bool scaleUp = false;
    private float oldDuration;

    private void Start()
    {
        oldDuration = duration;

        if (oppositeDirection)
        {
            Vector3 tempMin = minSize;
            Vector3 tempMax = maxSize;

            minSize = tempMax;
            maxSize = tempMin;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEyes; i++)
        {
            GameObject eye = Instantiate(eyePrefab);
            foreach (Transform child in eye.transform)
            {
                child.localScale = minSize;
                eyesparts.Add(child.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (automatic)
        {
            if (oldDuration != duration && duration >= 0)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                oldDuration = duration;
                Scale();
            }

            if (!coroutineIsRunning)
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                if (duration > 0)
                {
                    StopAllCoroutines();
                    Scale();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Scale()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        for (int i = 0; i < eyesparts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (scaleUp)
            {
                if (randomDuration)
                {
                    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(eyesparts[i], maxSize, Random.Range(0.1f, 1)));
                }
                else
                {
                    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(eyesparts[i], maxSize, duration));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(eyesparts[i], minSize, duration));
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            if (counter > duration)
                coroutineIsRunning = false;

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, reduce your sample code to a [mcve], so we can narrow our attention to just the problematic part and we can run and the test the code

Comment: you made your code much more complicated when you changed it from scaling a single object to scaling a List of objects. the `coroutineIsRunning` variable is there to ensure the coroutine runs only once for a single object, but now you have multiple objects and now you have to keep track for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
private bool coroutineIsRunning = false;
```

to

```
private List<bool> coroutineIsRunning;
```

and make it the same length as `private List<GameObject> eyesparts`

that way you can know if the coroutine is running for each specific eye part with different duration

though at this point, this is going to make your code harder to read and harder to maintain... perhaps you should consider breaking the code up into smaller pieces